# I do not see a trendline section in Google Charts

Tags: trendline

I want to add a trendline to a Google line chart. When I scroll to the bottom of the customize section there is no trendline section visible.

Answer (score 0):

In your configuration for chart add 'trendLines' field such as:

```
otherOption: otherValue,
...
trendlines : { 
            0: {
            'color': 'red',
            'lineWidth': 6,
            'opacity': 0.4,
            'type': 'linear',
            'pointSize': 0,
            'visibleInLegend': true,
            'labelInLegend': 'Failing trend'
            },
 ...
```

where '0' above is the data set you will use as a source.